# Linear mixed model with repeated measures sample size

Tags: r, statistics

I have a pilot study about testing 2 drugs and a control(placebo) to see which drug is more effective. The design is as follows:

- drug 1 is given to 5 random people then the response is measured 5 times for each person
- drug 2 is given to a different 5 random people and the response is measured 5 times for each person
- the control group: placebo is given to a different 5 random people and the response is measured 5 times for each person

My question is using this pilot study, how to determine the sample size for each group, which means how many patients in each category (drug 1, drug 2, control) should be not the measurements?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

My reading of this is that your sample size (the smallest number of discrete, theoretically independent samples) is 15 total (assuming no person was given two different drugs), and n = 5 for each drug. If you count each measurement as an individual sample, you run the risk of pseudoreplication. Additionally, drug responses over time from the same individual are unlikely to be independent. Hope that helps.

Comment: actually I'm trying to see how many persons in each drug should be the pilot study is 5, but in general how many persons should be in each category and not the measurments

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a power analysis in order to decide how many patients to enroll. This is typically done by choosing a desired power level (typically 80%) and assuming some minimum effect size you're okay with detecting.

I don't think this is a question for stackoverflow (which is focused on solving coding problems). Consider posting on crossvalidated.

Comment: I did post it on crossvalidate and I added the data , no one helped

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the crossvalidated post?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216210/linear-mixed-model-with-repeated-measures-sample-size